# How does the maneuverability of the FJ-2 Fury and F-86 compare?

Tags: aircraft-performance, fighter

The North American FJ-2 Fury was the US Navy version of the F-86 Sabre jet.

I want to know if G maneuver limits were in favor of the F-86 or the FJ-2 Fury.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_FJ-2/-3_Fury) explains the differences quite well.

Comment: I want to know  G  maneouvres   limits were in favor of the F86 OR   FJ2 Fury

Comment: OK, I updated your question to include that. Feel free to edit again, if you want to know something else.

Comment: Interesting. Apparently it can sometimes happen on ASE, with some browsers, that one can be viewing the older version of a question, and can submit an upvote or downvote, not knowing that the question has actually been changed. Then when one refreshes the question and sees the change, it is already too late to submit a new vote. Good to know.